# Update the public folder file but don't want to reset after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a json file called "stats.json" which is initially empty (e.g. `{}`) in my rails application's public folder. I pushed the file in github.

This file will update based on some scenario.

The problem is each time I deploy the code to the server, the file changes to initial state (e.g. `{}`) and all the update that's written in the file resets.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a deployment tool like Capistrano or Mina, you can add stats.json to the list of symlinked files that are persisted across deployments

Using Capistrano in your deploy.rb file:

`set :linked_files, %w{public/stats.json}`

Using Mina in your deploy.rb file:

`set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('public/stats.json')`

The initial blank stats.json file will need to be uploaded to your Capistrano/Mina shared folder, for example `/home/user/rails/your-app/shared/public/stats.json`